# vuejs Выполнение dispatch

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как правильно будет выполнить dispatch action модуля склада?

В модулe склада `laboratory.js` получаю данные из БД и сохраняю в переменную модуля.

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        laboratories: null,
    },
    getters: {
        getLaboratories(state){
            return state.laboratories;
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        loadLaboratories(state, data){
            state.laboratories = data;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        loadLaboratories(store){
            // store.commit('clearLaboratory');
            Vue.http.get('laboratories')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    store.commit('loadLaboratories', data);
                });
        },
    }
};
```

В главном файле склада подключаю модуль

```
import laboratory from './modules/laboratory';
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        laboratory,
    },
...
```

Теперь я хочу вызвать `action loadLaboratories` в одном из компонентов. Можно вызвать напрямую, если в модуле корзины прописать `import Vue from 'vue';`

```
this.$store.dispatch('laboratory/loadLaboratories');
```

Или же следует в компоненте сделать как-то так (смотри ниже).

```
import {mapActions} from 'vuex';

export default {
    methods: {
        ...mapActions('laboratory', {
            loadLaboratories: 'loadLaboratories',
        })
    },
...
```

И потом вызвать выполнение строкой `this.loadLaboratories();`?

Как правильно? И ещё вопрос - как следует именовать методы в state, getters, mutations, actions и переменные внутри модулей? Например, в моё случае из БД я буду получать `laboratories` (их будет несколько). Значит нужно всё именовать во множественном числе? Или в единственном?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как правильно будет выполнить dispatch action модуля склада?

Оба примеры правильны.

```
 this.$store.dispatch('laboratory/loadLaboratories');
```

используется для импорта одной функции.

**mapActions** - это всего лишь helper который упрощает экспорт множества функций. Например если у вас 2 и более функции которые надо сделать доступными в компоненте
то удобнее использовать:

```
...mapActions['method1', 'method2', 'method3']
```

> как следует именовать методы в state, getters, mutations, actions и переменные внутри модулей?

Вы можете как использовать множественное число для описания методов, так и нейтральные названия такие как
**getAll, getById, set, save** etc.
 при использовании namespase "laboratory" все будет не менее понятно.